# how can I get on('click') to reset to the onload state after the click without a page refresh?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textbox where the user inputs a location name then click a button to check availability. On the on('click') event handler the script uses post() to verify the availability then show if it is available or not to the user and then fades out.

Everything works fine. However, if the user attempts to make a change for whatever reason like a typo, nothing happens. How can I get on('click') to reset to the onload state after the click without a page refresh?

I have tried several different things but can't seem to get it. Being new to jquery I am not sure what I am leaving out.

Here is my code:

```
 $('#ckAval').on('click', function() {
        var locName = $('#locName').val();
        var url = $('#locNameVal').val();
        var postit = $.post( url, { locName:locName } );        
        postit.done(function( data ) {$( "#ckLocName" ).html( data ).delay( 300  ).fadeOut( "slow");})          
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="small-9 columns">
    <input type="text"  id="locName" name="location_name" placeholder="Enter Unique Location Name here..." value="'.$location_name.'" />
    <input type="hidden" id="locNameVal" value="'.$p_queries.'unique-location-name-query.php">
</div>

<div id="ckAval" class="small-3 columns">
    <span class="postfix">Check Availability</span>
</div>

<div id="ckLocName" class="text-center"></div>
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance:
Pete

Comment: "reset to the onload state" not sure what you mean, can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: when the page loads the on('click') works the first time around but if you attempt to make a change to the entered name and click the check availability a second time nothing happens. I will try fiddle.

Comment: ok, in your code you fade out a div, so I'd expect nothing to happen if you did click t again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `fadeOut` has the effect of hiding the element, so the second time you try to put content in that element its invisible.

I have reproduced the issue below (click the button and a message is shown, click it again and it *looks* like the message is not working anymore - but the problem is the element is hidden)

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/ezxmnb6e/

This can be fixed by simply making sure the element is visible before displaying the message in it. A simple change of one line:

```
// note the `show()` chained in.
$( "#ckLocName" ).show().html( data ).delay( 300  ).fadeOut( "slow");
```

Try it now: http://jsfiddle.net/ezxmnb6e/1/

Comment: But wouldn't that mean a user only has 300ms to update the input#ckLocName value?

Comment: @atmd what? no! It has nothing to do with the user. That code executes in a `$.post` callback.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, isn't the OP asking how to set the initial state of the form? once you click it you hide the input, so you can't edit the location and click again. (unless I've misunderstood)

Comment: @atmd it is not the textbox which is fading out... it is the results div. Jamiec was correct. after fading out the results div I never showed it again. By adding .show() it insures the the results div is visible.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the issue

The event does fire, but the div is already hidden after the first click

add this:

```
 $('#ckAval').on('click', function() {
        var locName = $('#locName').val();
        var url = $('#locNameVal').val();
        var postit = $.post( url, { locName:locName } );        
        postit.done(function( data ) {$( "#ckLocName" ).html( data ).delay( 300  ).fadeOut( "slow");})          
    });

$('#locNameVal').on('keyup', function () {
    $("#ckLocName").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

This will reset the form if the users changes the location after clicking

Comment: Not sure you need a fade in on every keyup! You could just show the div and empty it at the beginning of the `on(...)` like `$('#ckLocName').empty().show()`

Comment: My understanding is that fadeIn() will be ignored if the element is already visible

Comment: There's little point fading in if an element is visible. Whats your point?

Comment: I agree, what I'm saying is, that as far as I am aware, a call to fadeIn on an already visible element is ignored (i.e. jquery ignores the call/does nothing with it)

Comment: I tried this and it did not work... I also ttied $('#ckLocName').empty().show() which did not work as well... thanks for the effort though